# ros_arduino_bridge with two arduinos

Tags: ros, arduino, package, ros-arduino-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i  want to use the ros_arduino_bridge package on a Wild Thumper plattform. I  have the Dagu T'Rex as motor driver but the encoder function  of it is useless for odometry. So i haveto use an Arduino Mega2560 for encoders and odometry.

Now to my question. Is it possible to use both arduino at the same time with the ros_arduino_bridge package ? Or can this package used only with one arduino?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245041/ros_arduino_bridge-with-two-arduinos/) by [anonymous26353](https://answers.ros.org/users/26353/anonymous26353/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should be possible to use two Arduino's simultaneously by assigning each node a distinct name and config file in your launch file(s).  I don't have my Arduinos in front of me to test, but something like this should work:

```
<launch>
   <node name="arduino1" pkg="ros_arduino_python" type="arduino_node.py" output="screen" clear_params="true">
      <rosparam file="$(find my_arduino_pkg)/config/arduino1_params.yaml" command="load" />
   </node>
   
   <node name="arduino2" pkg="ros_arduino_python" type="arduino_node.py" output="screen" clear_params="true">
      <rosparam file="$(find my_arduino_pkg)/config/arduino2_params.yaml" command="load" />
   </node>
</launch>
```

Of course, you need to change the paths to your config files.  When subscribing to sensor data connected to arduino1, you would look under the namespace /arduino1/sensor and for arduino2, /arduino2/sensor.

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2016-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous26353](https://answers.ros.org/users/26353/anonymous26353/) on 2016-10-05**:
Thanks sounds really great! Will try it tommorrow and give a feedback :)

Do i have to uncomment the encoder function, when i use the rosarduinobridge.ino for the motor controller and the other way around for the mega board to avoid problems (like disturbing each other)?

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2016-10-06**:
After further consideration, I don't believe it is currently possible to do what you want.  The trouble is that there can only be one base_controller object that both reads encoder counts and sends motor commands...

**Comment by [anonymous26353](https://answers.ros.org/users/26353/anonymous26353/) on 2016-10-06**:
Ok, then i have to look for an other option. Thank you very much for your help!